# Can i use Azure Managed Identity in a Console application deployed in On-Premises Server?

Tags: azure, console, azure-keyvault

I have a console application that is going to be deployed on an On-Premises Server (Not an Azure-hosted one). Can I make use of Managed Identities to retrieve a secret from my azure key vault? Is it possible... please guide me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use Managed Identity (both system assigned and user assigned) outside of Azure. They can only be used with resources running in Azure.

What you would need to do is connect to your Key Vault using a Service Principal (using client id and client secret or certificate) and retrieve secrets that way.

Comment: Great ! Thanks Gaurav Mantri.